# Robot framework installation issues on Windows

Tags: robotframework

I am completely new to robot framework. Thus, I am unable to install robot framework on my system.

Basically I tried installing Python and pre required stuff on system even that is throwing errors. Can someone please share the step by step guide for same? I tried following YouTube videos but not working.

I am using Windows-32 bit.

Comment: When I first started out - I used this tutorial to get my install working. It should work for you too: http://www.swtestacademy.com/getting-started-robotframework/

Comment: There are already step-by-step instructions for installing robot here: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#installation-instructions

Comment: I recommend _against_ trying to use RIDE. There are plenty of better editing options that are less of a hassle to install. See http://robotframework.org/#tools

Comment: @rob: that link isn't for instructions for installing robot, it's for installing RIDE. Those are two different things. RIDE is an IDE, robot is the actual test runner.

Comment: Pro-tip for posting: if you are having problems with something, and you mention that you are getting errors, **always** say what those errors are. Please edit your question with this detail.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Robot Framework is just a two-step process.

1. install python from https://www.python.org/downloads/
   (pip is also installed by default if you are using Python 2 >=2.7.9 or Python 3 >=3.4.)
2. install robotframework from https://pypi.org/project/robotframework/ > "pip install robotframework" (You can check the version by > "robot --version")

Read more - https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#installation-instructions